# How to convert 4 Digit HEX (2 byte) to Decimal (Floating) Value Using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I don't know much about VB.Net. I have `D30E` Hex value and I want to convert it to `-11506` using VB.Net.

I use the following code but I did not get proper value and I am looking for simple code.

```
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(&HD30E))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(&HD30E))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(&HD30E, 16))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt64(&HD30E, 16))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(&HD30E, 16))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToUInt64(&HD30E, 16))
```

Another example is `FFCO` value want to convert to `-64`

Comment: You seem to need quite a bit of help with this given the amount of questions you've asked, and so far it's mostly been about smaller things. If you'd like I can help you via e-mail instead, as this may go out of the scope of Stack Overflow. If so, you can find my contact address here: https://support.mydoomsite.com/

Comment: This is the 6th question you have posted in the last two days that all concern hex data strings and converting them to some kind of number. It's not clear which of these are separate questions and which are reworded versions of the same question. You should only ask each question once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a constant, convert it from a string into a `Short` (Int16) instead:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt16("0xD30E", 16))
```

If you need it to be a `Decimal` just convert the result once more:

```
Dim Value As Short = Convert.ToInt16("0xD30E", 16)
ListBox1.Items.Add(CType(Value, Decimal))
```

Less readable, but more compact:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(CType(Convert.ToInt16("0xD30E", 16), Decimal))
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much

Comment: Even more compact, and I think more readable, could be to use CDec instead of CType(x, Decimal).

Comment: @AndrewMorton : True. I usually avoid using VB-specific methods because I dislike them. :)